# Return statement with logic built into it

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I know this is probably a really simple question, but I ran across this in some code on a project today. How does the return statement work? What kind of operation is this? Is it similar to a tertiary operator?

The variable access is an int.

```
return access != IACL.RS_NOACCESS && documentVersion >= 0;
```

Comment: No; those are regular logical operators.   That is not fundamentally different from `1*2+3*4`

Comment: It returns a `boolean` saying whether or not that logical expression is true.

Comment: If in doubt, enclose the expression in parentheses. It's just `return (some expression)`, not more complex than `return (1+2)`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html - see the example; things after the `return` are evaluated and returned.

Comment: I would recommend not always doing this, it might reduce the readability of the code.

Comment: On the contrary, I highly recommend this as more readable than introducing yet another useless local variable.

Comment: Whether or not breaking this down into more expressions makes code more readable is an age old discussion. I don't want to say that either way is right or wrong, though my point of view is closer to @MarkoTopolnik's.

Comment: @Renan I just feel it is right to state that there are opposing views on this, and no clear one-size-fits-all recommendation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's break it down, using parentheses to make the logical groupings explicit:

```
return ((access != IACL.RS_NOACCESS) && (documentVersion >= 0));
```

So, the method returns a boolean value, the result of the comparisons being performed. The entire expression is evaluated before the expression's value is returned.

Let's pretend that `access` is equal to `IACL.RS_NOACCESS` and `documentVersion` is equal to `1`. Then the statement reduces to:

```
return ((IACL.RS_NOACCESS != IACL.RS_NOACCESS) && (1 >= 0));
```

and that evaluates to:

```
return ((false) && (true));
```

and that evaluates to:

```
return false;
```

One important note, pointed out by Ryan in a comment: logical operators like && and || are  "short-circuiting" in most languages, in most scenarios. They are in Java. This means that evaluation proceeds from left to right. If there's no point in evaluating the second part of the expression, then it won't be evaluated.

In the case above, since the first part of the expression evaluates to false, it doesn't matter what the second part of the expression evaluates to - given the AND truth table, the full expression will always evaluate to false. In fact, you could have an expression that generates a run-time error on the right side - it doesn't matter. With these values, the right side never be run.

Comment: Something that may be important to note is that if the first statement is false, the operation will short-circuit and return false, because `false && a` is always false. So `false && a()` will not call `a()`. If you want to force calling `a()` regardless, use `false & a()`

Comment: Good call, @Ryan. Added a discussion.

Comment: @RyanAmos can you give an example of a circumstance where you would  want to force calling `a()`?

Comment: If `a()` changes the state. You need both actions to be performed, but if either action fails, you want to return false. I remember having to deal with this in the past, but I can't come up with any good examples off the top of my head.

Comment: @Trevor Used one today `if(finder.isDirectoryExSTraCS(finder.chooser.getCurrentDirectory())|| JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(finder, "It doesn't appear that this directory is an ExSTraCS directory. Proceed anyways?", "Wrong Directory", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)`

Answer (score 5):

The whole expression to the right of `return` evaluates to a boolean value, which is what's returned.

```
return access != IACL.RS_NOACCESS && documentVersion >= 0;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
boolean result = (access != IACL.RS_NOACCESS);
result = result && (documentVersion >= 0);
return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to:

```
boolean valid = access != IACL.RS_NOACCESS && documentVersion >= 0;
return valid;
```

It just eliminates the variable since it's not necessary to store the result of `access != IACL.RS_NOACCESS && documentVersion >= 0`. It's just to save space, basically.